# getting unhandled exception in try catch block java

Tags: java, lambda, try-catch, unhandled-exception

I have added try catch block in my code eventhough am getting compile time error saying unhandled exception.

```
try {
    aList.stream.forEach(a->bList.addAll(getAValues(a)));
}catch(CustomizedException e){
    log.debug(e.getMessage());
}
```

the getAValues(String a) method is throwing the same "CustomizedException". But still getting unhandled Exception.

```
getAValues(String a) throws CustomizedException {
     //some code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exception needs to be caught inside your lambda expression body

```
aList.stream.forEach(a -> {
   try {
    bList.addAll(getAValues(a))
   } catch(CustomizedException cex) {
     // handle it
   }
});
```